# Sum values with same id from a list of ids

Tags: php, sql, foreach, while-loop, sum

I'm totally a begginer trying to get this done. I get a list of ids from a query as 1,2,3,4... then I need to SUM the values of a column named "total" where the id includes one of the ids listed.

```
//Total quoted
//$array_quos = $row3['quo_list'];
$array_quos = explode(',', $row3['quo_list']);
foreach ($array_quos as $qtid => $qt)
{
  $qt = $db->query("SELECT total FROM exp.quo_main WHERE quo_id = '.$qtid.' ");
  $total_quoted2 += $qt;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you give sample input & expected output?

Comment: `SELECT SUM(total) as total_quoted FROM exp.quo_main WHERE quo_id IN(?)` then bind it to `$row3['quo_list']`

Comment: Awesome, works great. It was so simple and i was so lost

//Total quoted
$array_quos = $row3['quo_list'];
$total_quoted2b = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT SUM(total) as total_quoted FROM exp.quo_main WHERE quo_id IN ($array_quos)");
$total_quoted2= mysqli_fetch_array($total_quoted2b);
//echo $total_quoted2[0];